# Here maps with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, here-api, here-maps-rest

I plan to use here api to reduce my costs compared to google maps.

Is there a way to use the here map in Xamarin forms?

I have already designed the search combo suggestion to find places. Now I would like to show the places on the here map.

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=here+map+xamarin+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use android studio. The Xamarin bindings still need to be created in the SDK, as the are not on our roadmap yet.
But you can either create the bindings yourself.